# how to stream 2 million small (2MB files) from S3 on an EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have ~ 2 million 2MB files in S3.

What's the best way to simultaneously stream these files to an EC2 instance programatically in python?

Will the creation of 2 million simultaneous TCP connections on a single instance be a challenge?

My understanding is that each TCP connection can take 32K memory for TCP state data structures and buffers, and it takes ~10ms to setup each connection.

So 2 million connections would take 64GB of memory.

Assuming I have an instance with enough memory, what other challenges might I face?  Limit in OS file descriptors?

Comment: What do you mean by 'stream'? Do you just mean read/download? How do you intend triggering this many API calls simultaneously to Amazon S3?

Comment: 'stream' usually means getting a stream of data.  s3 isn't a stream of data it is distiinct objects.  Please make it clear what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Each 2MB file contains a set of rows.  I would like to have a stream of per 2MB file, reading a row a file at a time across 2 million files.  @John, yes, one question I have is whether it's even possible to open 2 million TCP connections from a EC2 single instance to S3.

Comment: At a high-level, what are you wanting to accomplish from all these files? That is, what type of processing are you doing? There might be a more cloud-friendly way to achieve it, such as using Amazon Kinesis, Amazon EMR or Amazon Athena.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I think the solution is to store files in Parquet format in S3, and S3 SELECT can be used to filter rows in each file.